# Bash - awk comparison not working as expected

Tags: csv, awk

I have tried a lot of solutions for my code but none of those solutions worked for me. Actually I don't know why I am having an issue because as far as I understand AWK command, everything seems fine.

THE PROBLEM:
I have a csv file and a group of variables. First of all, Theres a loop that iterates over that group of variables, and for each variable I am executing the awk command, with the following instructions.

`awk -F, -v mail="$cleanedmail" 'BEGIN {print "header1,header2,header3,password"}{if (mail == $1) print $0",FOUNDED"} myFile.csv > resultFile.csv`

What I expect the awk command to do is:
define 2 variables via the -v option: mail and hash
use the comma as a separator via the -F option
before processing, write headers (header1, header2 ...etc) to the very first line of a csv file
evaluate a condition: if mail matches the value in column 1, then print the entire current row add a comma and add the hash variable.

It does almost everything. The comparison keeps failing.

**But when I change the mail variable with a value that is in myFile.csv, the comparison works fine.**

For example, myFile.csv looks like this:

[image: csv file evaluated by AWK command]

And the loop (REMEMBER that for each email in an array of data Im calling the awk command, the variable actually change with every iteration) is performed over an array of emails, like this:
`emails=["someone@fakeemail.com", someone@bademail.com", "someone@gmail.com"]`

So Im expecting the code to iterate and return something like this:

[image: EXPECTED RESULT]

But nothing works if I do the comparison in awk like this:

```
if ($1 == mail)
```

If I do

```
if ($1 == "someone@gmail.com")
```

then I got the desired result

At first I thought that my mail variable wasnt actually equal to the $1 column so I confirmed it first. I did (REMEMBER: cleanedmail is set to be the mail variable in awk command):

```
if [[ "$cleanedmail" = "someone@gmail.com" ]]; then
echo "same"
else
echo "NOT"
fi
```

before calling the awk command, and the echo shows this (for the array mentioned before):

NOT

NOT

same

At the end, in awk comparison:

```
$1 == mail -> NOT WORKING
$1 == "someone@gmail.com" -> WORKS
```

outside awk comparison:

```
mail == "someone@gmail.com" -> WORKS
```

**WHY THE FIRST COMPARISON ISNT WORKING THEN?**

Thanks in advance.
AND Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to contain concise, testable, **textual** sample  input and expected output. No links and no images, just the text exactly as stored on your computer.

Comment: Also try `-v mail="someone@gmail.com"` - if that works then it's a problem with your `cleanedmail` variable value.

Comment: @EdMorton thanks for your comments. After testing the -v option as you said, it works, so the problem is with the actual cleanedmail variable. I will close this question and if needed, create a new one with the correct information. Thanks again.